# How to calulate SUM previous and current row value in MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, select, sum

My table is "Activity_table", which have 4 columns. How can I create a function, which SUM each Peroson 2 previous and current activities?
My Activity_table

```
ID  PID AID Act
1   1   1   12
2   1   2   32
3   2   1   5
4   1   3   21
5   2   2   12
6   2   3   19
7   1   4   11
8   2   4   6
```

PID-PersonID; AID-ActivitieID; Act-Activitie Value

My target:

```
ID  PID AID Act SUM
1   1   1   12  12
2   1   2   32  44
3   2   1   5   5
4   1   3   21  65
5   2   2   12  17
6   2   3   19  36
7   1   4   11  64
8   2   4   6   37
```

Sum1=12; Sum2=32+12; Sum3=5; Sum4=21+32+12; Sum5=12+5; Sum6=19+12+5; Sum7=11+21+32; Sum8=6+19+12; Thank you,

Comment: Why use abbreviations? A year from now, you will have no idea what these mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use the two previous and the current row,

```
SELECT ID,PID,AID,Act,
    (SELECT SUM(Act) 
     FROM Activity_table 
     WHERE ID <= a.ID
     AND ID >= a.ID - 2
     AND PID = a.PID) 
FROM Activity_table a;
```

Comment: Doesn't this assume that all IDs are perfectly numbered incrementally?

Answer (score 1):

You are taking the SUM according to the PID right? Then the last two rows of your target should be modified as,

```
7   1   4   11  **76**
8   2   4   6   **42**
```

The most flexible query is for your requirement is,

```
SELECT ID,PID,AID,Act,
    (SELECT SUM(Act) 
     FROM Activity_table 
     WHERE ID <= a.ID
     AND PID = a.PID) 
FROM Activity_table a;
```

Then if you need only the flow of SUM of a particular PID, you can change it like this,

```
SELECT ID,PID,AID,Act,
    (SELECT SUM(Act) 
     FROM Activity_table 
     WHERE ID <= a.ID
     AND PID = a.PID) 
FROM Activity_table a
WHERE PID = 2;
```

Result:

```
ID  PID AID Act SUM
3   2   1   5   5
5   2   2   12  17
6   2   3   19  36
8   2   4   6   42
```

Comment: Yes, according to the PID, but i need youst two previous and current activities sum.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the previous wrong Answers (deleted).
This produces the correct answer based on your example:

```
SET @LastPID = 0, @Act1 = 0,@Act2 = 0,@Act3 = 0;
SELECT ID,PID,AID,Act,`SUM` FROM 
    (
    SELECT ID,PID,AID,Act,@Act3 := IF(@LastPID != PID, 0,@Act2),@Act2 := IF(@LastPID != PID, 0,@Act1), @Act1 := Act, @Act1 + @Act2 + @Act3 `SUM`, @LastPID := PID
    FROM Activity_table
    ORDER BY PID,ID
    ) sm
ORDER BY ID
;
```